# Turn JSON (as String) into Multidimensional Array

Tags: javascript, json, flot

I'm trying to take a hideous JSON string - it shows up in the console like this:

```
"[[\"a\",1],[\"b\",2],[\"c\",3],[\"d\",4]]"
```

... and turn it into a multidimensional array for use in Flot.js.

Flot.js will take in input like this just fine:

```
var data = [["January", 10], ["February", 8], ["March", 4], ["April", 13], ["May", 17], ["June", 9]];
```

But not my code ...

```
var data = "[[\"a\",1],[\"b\",2],[\"c\",3],[\"d\",4]]";
var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
```

... nor this ...

```
var data = [\"a\",1],[\"b\",2],[\"c\",3],[\"d\",4];
var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
```

... etc.  What approach should I be taking?

Comment: Use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your JSON. If it's not valid then start by making sure it's valid.

Comment: In Chrome at least, this works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/dgVZE/

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/ZrP3x/

Comment: Works fine for me too.  I went both ways with it. http://jsfiddle.net/Uqj3z/

Comment: @Jared, jsonlint looks like a very helpful utility, thanks very much.

Comment: The jsfiddles appear to be creating javascript objects, but not two-dimensional arrays: http://jsfiddle.net/ZrP3x/1/

Comment: `typeof [] === "object"`. Try it. Type in `typeof []` into your JavaScript console, it'll output `"object"`.

Comment: Also, try `console.log(d);` in your fiddle, you'll see that it outputs a two-dimensional array.

Comment: Arrays in JS are objects whose properties are all integers.

Comment: The object created by JSON.parse(data) doesn't work as input in flot.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found the solution for this particular case. Starting with the data object:

```
var s = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
var t = "[" + s + "]";
var u = jQuery.parseJSON(t);
```

the u object becomes acceptable input for Flot.js.  Although I'm not entirely sure if this is the best approach, or why this worked.